# Implementing an Alternative to Adobe AIR in for Linux

Tags: linux, flash, air, adobe

I use a product called [ReadCube](http://www.readcube.com/) on my desktop, and the creators haven't developed a version for Linux because AIR for Linux does not include many features the same way the Mac and Windows versions do, and so the development of a Linux version would be difficult for them to do.  From reading adobe's website, it looks like there won't be any updated version of AIR for linux anytime soon.

I'd like to know if it would be feasible for one person to develop an alternative to AIR for Linux that app developers could build upon. I'm not sure what this would entail as I can't see the source code for AIR so I'm not sure what technology is involved aside from the short wiki description that it allows developers to combine HTML, Javascript, Flash and other things to make applications.

Comment: Honestly adobe abandoned flex. I doubt that this product has bright future. Would you invest your time to develop Linux port?

Comment: Did you mean "Would I invest my time to develop 'a' Linux port"? If so yes. I actually considered this before considering making an AIR alternative, I just figured it'd be more useful for everyone to create the underlying libraries that could be re-used. If you think it'd be a better investment of time to make a Linux port however then I suppose that may be the way for me to go.

Comment: I think it is too huge task for single person.

Comment: It WOULD be feasible if you could invest 5 or 10 man-years in the project. But why bother? I like Linux too, but if I've got a great tool in my Windows toolbox I don't think, first, of re- inventing the tool. I just USE what I've got!

Comment: maybe the app you want could be compiled with the 2.7 AIR SDK  that works on Linux, there are not many features that landed for desktop, Adobe put all the focus on mobile.